# iPad: Save Photo in Specific Album

Tags: ipad, uiimage, save

I want to save a UIImage in different folder which is displayed in album section of Default Photo application of iPad. I am able to save photo in album "Saved Photos" using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function. but i also want to save it in different album which is already created.  Whether it is possible in iPad ? if Yes, then how can I achieve this task ?

Please suggest

Comment: Find the below link it may help to your question. http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/